# Setting the Search Path for Plug In (Bundle / DyLib)

Tags: xcode, macos, openmp, dylib, icc

I'm creating a Photoshop Plug In on OS X (Basically a Bundle / DyLib).
I'm using Intel Compiler and uses OpenMP by linking against OpenMP (`libiomp5`).
When I use Static Linking it crashes Photoshop (Only on OS X, on Windows it works).
So I tried dynamic linking.

The host, Photoshop, uses by itself `libiomp5.dylib` which is available on its Framework folder.
So, on Xcode I set on the Linking Part the `Runpath Search Paths` to `@executable_path/../Frameworks/` yet when I try to load it on Photoshop it won't work.
I also tried to set `Runpath Search Paths` to [Intel Run Time Redistributable Libraries](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intelr-composer-redistributable-libraries-by-version) (Which include all DyLib needed for the Plug In according to [MacDependency](https://github.com/kwin/macdependency), just like Photoshop's Framework library) yet still it won't load on Photoshop.

When I use otool -L on the Plug In, I get:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 157.0.0)
    libimf.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libsvml.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libirng.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libiomp5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
    libintlc.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.13.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 62.0.0)
```

When I tried `otool -l` on the Plug In I do see what I insert in Xcode:

```
Load command 6
     cmd LC_UUID
 cmdsize 24
    uuid B61F2961-AD6D-30B9-AF58-C67689731966
Load command 7
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.7
      sdk 10.10
Load command 8
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 157.0.0
compatibility version 2.0.0
Load command 9
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 40
         name libimf.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 0.0.0
compatibility version 0.0.0
Load command 10
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 40
         name libsvml.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 0.0.0
compatibility version 0.0.0
Load command 11
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 40
         name libirng.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 0.0.0
compatibility version 0.0.0
Load command 12
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 40
         name libiomp5.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 5.0.0
compatibility version 5.0.0
Load command 13
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 120.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 14
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1213.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 15
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 40
         name libintlc.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 1.13.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 16
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 104
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 02:00:02 1970
      current version 62.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 17
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 48
         path @executable_path/../Frameworks/ (offset 12)
Load command 18
      cmd LC_FUNCTION_STARTS
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 3486976
 datasize 5616
Load command 19
      cmd LC_DATA_IN_CODE
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 3492592
 datasize 0
```

If I set the `Runpath Search Paths` to [Intel Run Time Redistributable Libraries](https://github.com/kwin/macdependency) I see the proper path as well, yet the result is the same.

Could anyone assist me with that?
I'm not very experience developer so, step by step would be great.

Comment: Reference -  http://qin.laya.com/tech_coding_help/dylib_linking.html

Comment: Reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991581/install-name-tool-to-update-a-executable-to-search-for-dylib-in-mac-os-x

Comment: Reference - http://thecourtsofchaos.com/2013/09/16/how-to-copy-and-relink-binaries-on-osx/

Comment: Reference - http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/4235/how-to-distribute-a-dylib-with-a-mac-os-x-application

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct for modern libraries that are aware of @rpath. OpenMP library supports @rpath starting compiler version 16.0 update 2. In your case your RPATH settings are ignored by system

Can you try to link with the with openmp library from photoshop? as I understand they did a workaround for this and updated install_name from libiomp5.dylib to "@executable_path/../Frameworks/libiomp5.dylib". so if you link to that library the openmp name in "otool -l" output will be changed to @executable_path/../Frameworks/libiomp5.dylib

some hints

1. If photoshop updates install name via install_name_tool

   ```
    $ otool -l ./a.out | grep omp
    name libiomp5.dylib (offset 24)
    # libiomp5.dylib was copied to the location with test 
    $ install_name_tool -id "@executable_path/../Frameworks/libiomp5.dylib" libiomp5.dylib
    $ LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LIBRARY_PATH icc -openmp test1.cpp 
    $ otool -l ./a.out | grep omp
    name @executable_path/../Frameworks/libiomp5.dylib (offset 24)
   ```
2. RPATH usage

   ```
   install_name_tool -id "@executable_path/../Frameworks/libiomp5.dylib" libiomp5.dylib
   $ LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LIBRARY_PATH icc -openmp test1.cpp -Wl,-rpath,.
   $ ./a.out
   dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libiomp5.dylib
     Referenced from: /nfs/inn/home/vpolin/mac/./a.out
     Reason: image not found
   Trace/BPT trap: 5
   $ install_name_tool -id "@rpath/libiomp5.dylib" libiomp5.dylib
   $ LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LIBRARY_PATH icc -openmp test1.cpp -Wl,-rpath,.
   $ otool -l ./a.out | grep omp
            name @rpath/libiomp5.dylib (offset 24)
   $ ./a.out
   4 8 8 8 8
   ```

--Vladimir